# How to block specific member from joining guild

Tags: lords-mobile

In the game Lord's Mobile, someone keeps joining our guild, even after a high ranking person in the guild kicks them out.  This is getting really old.  Is there a way to permanently block a user from continually joining our guild?

Answer (score 1):

Games like that usually have some kind of restrictions like "requiring leader/officer approval" before letting people in. I haven't played that particular game to know if that exists, but it is a very common one. If the setting is to just let anyone in, then you can't really do much about it.

Comment: This exists in Lord's Mobile. You can set the guild (R5 has to do this aka leader of guild), to not be open. If it is set to 'private' then other people must apply before being allowed to enter